# Typed.js script is not working in iPhone6, if any word will complete at the of the line in that case another word are not type, only showing cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, typed

For example line  - **"Meaningful solutions are created using robust technology"**
In iPhone 6 first line is end with **"Meaningful solutions are created using"** **'using'** word after that remaining word not showing only cursor is showing.

We are a collective  of methodical, fearless and passionate doers, discoverers and innovators

```
          <div class="type-wrap">
             <span style="font-size:30px;" >At Pinnove-</span>
           <div id="typed-strings">
            <p>Ideas come to life</p>
            <p>Meaningful solutions are created using robust technology</p>
            <p>And then deletes them.</p>
            <p>We help enterprises solve their toughest challenges</p>
          </div>
             <span id="typed" style=" word-wrap: break-word;"></span>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution and its working..

```
Used "white-space: pre-wrap;" property to span as bellow..

<span id="typed" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></span>
```